# How to get OpenCL support for navi10 GPUs from AMD?

Tags: kernel, amd-graphics, opencl, amdgpu-pro

For my **AMD Radeon RX 5700XT** I tried **amdgpu-pro** drivers (v19.50) installation on modern (kernel 5.3) **Ubuntu 18.04.3** as driver claims it's supported but compilation failed with C++ errors. Tried the same on `5.0` and `5.5.2` kernels with same results (on `5.5.2` kernel it was different error though: `<drm/drmP.h>: No such file or directory`).

Currently I'm on `kernel 5.5.2` with `mesa 19.3` installed. `clinfo` prints a lot of satisfying information seeming it's all cool, but with such tiny little line in-between:

> fatal error: cannot open file '/usr/lib/clc/gfx1010-amdgcn-mesa-mesa3d.bc': No such file or directory

which causes kernels compilation to fail (with the same error).

Anyone having any luck getting navi10 GPU OpenCL working on <s>Ubuntu</s> any distro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I couldn't manage **amdgpu**/**amdgpu-pro** driver to install on **Ubuntu 18.04** with *all* permutations of:

> kernels `5.0`,`5.2`,`5.3`,`5.4`,`5.5`
>
> gcc `7`,`8`,`9` (every version was giving different errors which I was fixing to just get other errors)
>
> **amdgpu** and **amdgpu-pro** versions `19.30`,`19.50`

But I **did** manage to get **OpenCL** working ;) What eventually succeeded for me:

- fresh **Ubuntu 18.04.3** [installation](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
- update kernel to version **5.4** with [ukuu](https://linuxhint.com/upgrade-kernel-ubuntu-1804/) (next (**mesa**) step fails on kernel version 5.5)
- reboot
- [install](https://sourcedigit.com/24980-how-to-install-mesa-19-3-in-ubuntu-19-10/) **mesa 19.3**:

  > sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
  >
  > sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  >
  > sudo apt-get update
- reboot
- install **OpenCL**:

  > sudo apt install opencl-headers ocl-icd-libopencl1 clinfo
  >
  > sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1 /usr/lib/libOpenCL.so

*P.S. Exploring and learning about **amdgpu-pro** sources while trying to fix compilation errors I discovered that AMD devs implement forthcoming GPUs directly within **mesa** open-source drivers and Linux kernel - months before GPUs even released. So, to jusfify AMD devs a bit, that's where the development focus is - not on **amdgpu-pro**.*

Comment: By now you're probably content with your setup and don't want to change anything, but the stable version of [kernel 5.5.6](https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/ChangeLog-5.5.6) released today and it seems to have addressed /most/ of our issues. Long story short, I removed OpenCL and the amdgpu 19.50 drivers that were downloaded from their site and stuck with the PPA repos. When I did the kernel update it detected the firmware and libraries I was missing (including OpenCL!), and after successful reboot my OpenCL tests worked.

Answer (score 1):

Glad you got it working, I saw your inquiry on a few other forums while trying to find a solution. I managed to get a somewhat working solution.

I also have the RX 5700XT, and I'm running `Pop!_OS 19.10` on `5.5.5-050505-generic`. For my PPA's, I have cappelikan, kisak, and oibaf; I suspect this is reproducible without them as I mainly have [a few of] them for general drivers (other than OpenCL).

I downloaded the amdgpu-pro drivers 19.50, and installed the following (in order):

```
Setting up amdgpu-core (19.50-967956) ...
Setting up amdgpu-pro-core (19.50-967956) ...
Setting up opencl-amdgpu-pro-comgr (19.50-967956) ...
Setting up opencl-amdgpu-pro-icd (19.50-967956) ...
Setting up libdrm2-amdgpu:amd64 (1:2.4.99-967956) ...
Setting up libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:amd64 (1:2.4.99-967956) ...
Setting up libopencl1-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (19.50-967956) ...
Setting up clinfo-amdgpu-pro (19.50-967956) ...
```

To test if OpenCL works, I ran `darktable-cltest` and looked for successful outputs when loading the opencl kernel.

There is a big 'but' in all this: I cannot boot successfully (black screen, flashing lines). I'd have to CTRL+ALT+F2 and run `./amdgpu-pro-install --uninstall` from the amdgpu-pro drivers directory, and then repeat the same steps above. I've tested this with the 5.3 and 5.5 kernel so far.

Comment: Oh, it installed!? Black screen is a big 'but' though :). Anyway, I don't understand how you managed to install `19.50` driver on `5.5` core since it compiles **drm** which fails with `couldn't find drp/drmP.h` and it's because [it was removed from linux kernel 5.5](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/574cc4539762561d96b456dbc0544d8898bd4c6e), but **in-kernel** driver [was fixed](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/fdf2f6c56e5e289c7d7e726b676aba25643b39a0) in response to `drmP.h` removal.

Comment: Yup, installing only those packages did not give any error. I'm not sure what else I can add, but have you tried using [ROCm](https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm/)? The closest to our setup would be ROCm 3.0, and its setup ships with OpenCL.

Comment: Yes, I tried **ROCm**, but also failed - can't remember my set up atm. Anyway, **ROCm** just tries to install the same **amdgpu-pro** drivers, which fails. I also installed [ComputeCpp from Codeplay](https://www.codeplay.com/products/computesuite/computecpp) (which should target **OpenCL** on **AMD**), but it again was failing with `cannot open file '/usr/lib/clc/gfx1010-amdgcn-mesa-mesa3d.bc'` error. Btw, I'm happy with my current **OpenCL** installation through `kernel 5.4` and `mesa 19.3` - everything works fine ;)

Comment: ComputeCpp only works with a specific older version of the drivers (see Platform Support Notes https://developer.codeplay.com/products/computecpp/ce/guides/platform-support#intel-3-intel-cpu-opencl-device-sse4-1-requirement) because AMD stopped providing support for SPIR in their drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness it should be added here that **libclc** was finally updated in January 2024.

Support for newer class Radeon hardware was added to libclc with LLVM MR [#78884](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/pull/78884) which will be regularly available in **LLVM 18**. Check this topic [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/44186) for more details.

So there should exist now *some* clover OpenCL support also for latest RDNA class hardware. But it should be regarded that this scenario is not really tested and the clover OpenCL API is overall not in a really good condition. There might exist especially problems with newer LLVM features like the "new" LLVM pass manager.

And by the way. There exist since quite some time no longer any support for GCN5 hardware in **ROCm**. But at least RDNA based GPUs should be supported.